# How to handle enum while transferring service layer to business layer?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, enums

I am using enum in my service layer. All doing good if i set value of enum vice versa i am not going to set its value than it gives me an error 
Error :

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

I have used enum in DataContract Class which will be used while database operation. 
I am using WCF Services to connect with DB with the use of Data Model. In some of the method i am using enum but in some methods i am not.
DataContract Class :

```
[DataMember]
public Enums.SearchType SearchType { get; set; }
```

Enum Declaration:

```
 public enum SearchType
    {
      Search = 'S',

      Export = 'E',

      Undefined = 0
    }
```

So what should i do in this case?? If anyone have any idea about this than please help me in this...

Thanx in Advance............

Comment: I think you're misusing enum. The values should be integer.

Comment: @flem: You mean i cant use it with string value?

Comment: They aren't strings, those are chars, which can be cast as ints, hence it compiles

Comment: i don't think the issue is directly related to the enum. Something else is causing an error. Change the config of your service to return errors so you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your enum type has a default value (0)

```
public SearchType
{
   Undefined = 0,
   ...
}
```

Enums are Int32 (unless specified otherwise). default(Int32) is 0. default(Enums.SearchType) will also be 0. If 0 is not defined in the enum, data contract deserialisation will fail.